# eulerr package in r display wrong fittings

Tags: r, eulerr

I am making a 4 dimensional euler diagram. All 4 groups have unique proportions but somehow eulerr package drew one group inside another group.

Here is the input:

```
glvenn_d <- c("Ato_gl" = 644, "Elav_gl" = 467, "Spa_gl" = 368,
              "gl_RNA_Seq" = 723, "Ato_gl&Elav_gl" = 343, "Ato_gl&Spa_gl" = 258, 
              "Ato_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 37, "Elav_gl&Spa_gl" = 614, 
              "Elav_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 71, "Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 39, 
              "Ato_gl&Elav_gl&Spa_gl" = 372, "Ato_gl&Elav_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 42, 
              "Ato_gl&Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 26, "Elav_gl&Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 69, 
              "Ato_gl&Elav_gl&Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 37)
glvd <- euler(glvenn_d)
plot(glvd)
```

And I got spa_gl inside Elav_gl.[image]

I want to know if it is possible to fix it in this package. I have double checked my numbers they should be correct. I also tried ellipse shape and still the same issue.

Comment: If you want to issue a bug report to the package author, you can do so at https://github.com/jolars/eulerr/issues

Comment: If `Elav_gl&Spa_gl` is greater than either `Elav_gl` or `Spa_gl`, then perhaps there is a problem with the data???

Comment: This data is shown as "discrete" data. What you asking is a "union" question. Here is the union data: glvenn <- c("Ato_gl" = 1759, "Elav_gl" = 2015, "Spa_gl" = 1783, "gl_RNA_Seq" = 1044, "Ato_gl&Elav_gl" = 794, "Ato_gl&Spa_gl" = 693, "Ato_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 142, "Elav_gl&Spa_gl" = 1092, 
               "Elav_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 219, "Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 171, "Ato_gl&Elav_gl&Spa_gl" = 409, "Ato_gl&Elav_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 79, "Ato_gl&Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 63, "Elav_gl&Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 106, 
               "Ato_gl&Elav_gl&Spa_gl&gl_RNA_Seq" = 37)

Comment: Does anyone know alternative packages in R or python or matlab that can plot a 4 dimensional euler diagram? (shape size proportional to number size)